# Creating Border in PHP around text

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a printable form where the information is pulled from a mysql database using php, and I want to make a boarder around some of the text in the form, but I have tried to use

`<div "style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"> </div>` But It comes up with a syntax error `Unexpected "<"`

and I have tried to use

```
p.two {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}
```

Then put this at the start of the echo

```
<p class="two">
```

But this did not work either. Here is my full code as it currently stands;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

p.two {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}

</style>

<body>

<p class="two">
    <strong><u><center><font size="10">Asset Form</font size="10"></center></u></strong>
</p>


<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "appuser1";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "acmefg_app";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, jobnumber, assetnumber, serialnumber, make, model, description, refrigeranttype, refrigerantqty, itemcondition, installdate, location, comments, maintcomp FROM appdata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row


     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
         echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
         echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Serial Number: " . $row["serialnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Make: " . $row["make"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Model: " . $row["model"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Description: " . $row["description"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigeranttype: " . $row["refrigeranttype"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigerantqty: " . $row["refrigerantqty"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> itemcondition: " . $row["itemcondition"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> installdate: " . $row["installdate"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> location: " . $row["location"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> comments: " . $row["comments"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> maintcomp: " . $row["maintcomp"] . "<br>";
     }


$conn->close();
?> 





</body>
</html>
```

I want everything that is in this section;

```
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
         echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
         echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Serial Number: " . $row["serialnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Make: " . $row["make"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Model: " . $row["model"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Description: " . $row["description"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigeranttype: " . $row["refrigeranttype"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigerantqty: " . $row["refrigerantqty"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> itemcondition: " . $row["itemcondition"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> installdate: " . $row["installdate"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> location: " . $row["location"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> comments: " . $row["comments"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> maintcomp: " . $row["maintcomp"] . "<br>";
     }
```

To be contained in a the border.
Could someone please help me work out how to do this?

Comment: change: `<div "style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"> </div>` to `<div style="border: 5px solid #555;"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove your first `"` in the div.

`<div "style="border: 5px solid #aaa;">`

should be changed to

`<div style="border: 5px solid #aaa;">`

---

You can place it wherever you want in your code. In your example you can use it like this:

```
echo '<div style="border: 5px solid #aaa;">';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
         echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
         echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Serial Number: " . $row["serialnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Make: " . $row["make"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Model: " . $row["model"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Description: " . $row["description"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigeranttype: " . $row["refrigeranttype"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigerantqty: " . $row["refrigerantqty"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> itemcondition: " . $row["itemcondition"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> installdate: " . $row["installdate"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> location: " . $row["location"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> comments: " . $row["comments"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> maintcomp: " . $row["maintcomp"] . "<br>";
     }

echo '</div>';
```

---

Look at this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4vg50yvn/2/) for examples on how to add border styles to different divs.

Or [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/4vg50yvn/4/) on how to use classes to apply styles.

Comment: hello,
I hate to seem stupid, and thank you for your answer, but where do I open and close this in the code because it still doesn't seem to be working?
Thanks

Comment: Also is there a reason my question is getting so many downvotes?

Comment: Yeah, it's because it considered 'such an easy thing' to solve. And with minimal debugging you would've found it yourself i guess. Anyway i have an example in my answer with a link where you can see how it works.

Comment: This worked, thanks. and sorry I am quite new to this.

Comment: @AlexWalker-Ingham As SuperDJ mentioned in his answer, it would be better to use stylesheets so it's easier to change colors borders etc. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4vg50yvn/4/) is an example to show you how handy it is. If you need help with stylesheets you can ask me or search on google. It's really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Correct inline css is like this

```
<div style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"> </div>
```

Remove double quotes in -> `"style=`

http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<div "style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"> </div>
```

to

```
<div style="border: 5px solid #555;"> </div>
```

To use it:

```
echo '<div style="border: 5px solid #555;">';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
         echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
         echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Serial Number: " . $row["serialnumber"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Make: " . $row["make"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Model: " . $row["model"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> Description: " . $row["description"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigeranttype: " . $row["refrigeranttype"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> refrigerantqty: " . $row["refrigerantqty"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> itemcondition: " . $row["itemcondition"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> installdate: " . $row["installdate"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> location: " . $row["location"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> comments: " . $row["comments"] . "<br>";
         echo "<br> maintcomp: " . $row["maintcomp"] . "<br>";
     }
echo '</div>';
```

But it might be better to use a class for the div. Then you are able to modify all the styling in a stylesheet.

For example:

```css
.product {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.product ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.product ul li {
  /* Nort West South East */
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <br> ID: 1<br>
  <br> Job number: 1234<br>
  <br> Asset number: 3546<br>
  <br> Serial Number: 45673453456<br>
  <br> Make: Bosch<br>
  <br> Model: 4765678<br>
  <br> Description: Example<br>
  <br> refrigeranttype: 4653456<br>
  <br> refrigerantqty: 3<br>
  <br> itemcondition: new<br>
  <br> installdate: 3-4-2014<br>
  <br> location: NY<br>
  <br> comments: none<br>
  <br> maintcomp: 5463456<br>
</div>

<!-- Or maybe even better -->

<div class="product">
  <ul>
    <li> ID: 1</li>
    <li> Job number: 1234</li>
    <li> Asset number: 3546</li>
    <li> Serial Number: 45673453456</li>
    <li> Make: Bosch</li>
    <li> Model: 4765678</li>
    <li> Description: Example</li>
    <li> refrigeranttype: 4653456</li>
    <li> refrigerantqty: 3</li>
    <li> itemcondition: new</li>
    <li> installdate: 3-4-2014</li>
    <li> location: NY</li>
    <li> comments: none</li>
    <li> maintcomp: 5463456</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello,
This is Very handy thanks! Unfortunately I cant accept more than one answer but this will help me more with the layout of the rest of the form.

Comment: You can unaccept an aswer and than accept a new / better one